# How multiples shell pipes with subprocess work?

Tags: python-2.7, shell, subprocess, pipe

I would like to get the same output as this shell code :

```
$ ping -c 1 192.168.1.18  | egrep "bytes from" | cut -d " " -f4
192.168.1.18:
```

This shellcode will ping 1 time 192.168.1.10.
Then it will grep the line containing "bytes from".
Finally, it will select the 4th column based on the delimiter " " (which a white space). The 4th column is just the IP address.

I think that I'm close to the solution but I have some trouble handling the subprocess function.

Here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

ps1 = subprocess.Popen(('ping','-c','1','10.11.1.220'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps2 = subprocess.Popen(('egrep', '-i', 'bytes from'), stdin=ps1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.call(['cut', '-d', '" "','-f','4'], stdin=ps2.stdout)
```

So this is the result I get with this code:

```
$ py ping-sweep.py 
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
$ grep: write error: Broken pipe
```

I think I'm close because with just one pipe the result is good.

Proof:

```
ps1 = subprocess.Popen(('ping','-c','1','10.11.1.220'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.call(['egrep', '-i', 'bytes from'], stdin=ps1.stdout)
```

Result ouput:

```
$ py ping-sweep.py 
64 bytes from 10.11.1.220: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=114 ms
```

Could help me getting away of this nightmare?

Thanks!

Steackfrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`" "` is shell syntax for a string with a single space. Since you are no longer running a shell, you should use the Python equivalent `' '`:

```
subprocess.call(['cut', '-d', ' ', '-f', '4'], stdin=ps2.stdout)
```

`'" "'` is instead a string of three characters, which is why `cut` complains about multiple delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

There are previous answers on that subject, you most likely need to escape both " with \"